# Packaging python scripts to .exe on Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, exe

I have been trying to package my python scripts into .exe setup for Windows. Is that any way I can do the same while running Ubuntu?

Comment: Look into PyInstaller.

Comment: For some reasons it isn't working on Windows at my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_freeze is another option for freezing cross-platform.